# JDBC setQueryTimeout returns invalid argument in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

The below code returns an "Invalid argument" exception on the last line of the code below in Google Apps Script.

```
var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);
var stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.setQueryTimeout(40);
```

According to Google's own documentation, the argument accepts an integer defining the timeout in seconds, so I can't see anything wrong with it.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc-statement#setquerytimeoutseconds

Also the documentation of java.sql.Statement (of which this Jdbc class is a direct port) doesn't give any hints as to were this could be wrong.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setQueryTimeout(int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For no apparent (and more importantly undocumented) reason the limit for the setQueryTimeout *seconds* parameter is set to 30 in Google Apps Script.

So the below code runs fine.

```
stmt.setQueryTimeout(30);
```